# Get image preview of multiple input files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `<input type="file" />` elements and for both of these inputs I want a different picture preview. However I only got it working for one input. How can do this for multiple input files?

I hope some of you have a good example for me, thank you in advance.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#image-1')
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img id="image-1" style=" height: 100%;" class="form-control" src="./Images/smc.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="bestand" name="userfile" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newname" value="SMC.png"><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img style=" height: 100%;" class="form-control" src="./Images/achtergrond.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="bestand" name="userfile1" type="file" /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newname1" value="achtergrond.png"><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control submit" id="bestand" type="submit" name="instellingen1" value="Bestand uploaden" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're only calling `readURL()` from the first input. You need to call it from all of them. You also need to amend your logic so that it works based on the HTML structure, not specific elements selected by `id`. To do that you can use DOM traversal to find the `img` related to the `input` which had a file selected. Specifically, the `closest()` and `find()` methods in this case. Try this:

```js
$('input:file').on('change', function() {
  var input = this;
  var $input = $(input);
  
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {      
      $input.closest('.form-group').prev('.form-group').find('img').prop('src', e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img style=" height: 100%;" class="form-control" src="./Images/smc.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="bestand" name="userfile" type="file" /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newname" value="SMC.png"><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img style=" height: 100%;" class="form-control" src="./Images/achtergrond.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="bestand" name="userfile1" type="file" /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newname1" value="achtergrond.png"><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control submit" id="bestand" type="submit" name="instellingen1" value="Bestand uploaden" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, be aware that you're using two versions of jQuery in your code which should be avoided. One is also the 'slim' version which does not have AJAX functionality, amongst other things. That's not inherently a mistake, just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, i will surely take your advices.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. This code will work for an infinite number of inputs, so long as the HTML is consistent.